# Rationale behind applying the same criteria to German.SE (e.g. num. answers/question) than programming sites?

Tags: discussion

When one sees what happens with math, physics, and specially with the sister sites where solutions are based on code (TeX and stackoverflow) and which automatically can deliver ten beautiful answers, German, and in general languages, are maybe are rigid enough to allow a single answer.

For instance, these are very good questions with less than 2.5 answers:

- [Weshalb werden manche Wörter mit Doppelvokal gedehnt („aa“, „ee“, …)?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1364/weshalb-werden-manche-w%C3%B6rter-mit-doppelvokal-gedehnt-aa-ee)
- ["Schlaf mir nicht ein" - warum "mir"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1410/schlaf-mir-nicht-ein-warum-mir)
- Many grammar questions have only one "solution". They are not based on an opinion, but on grammar rules.

Is it normal that the 2.5 answers/question is asked in the area.51 to this site?

Paraphrased: Is it really healthy that only the said ratio 2.5 is asked as "good", if by adding answers one can even be superfluous?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, having 2.5 answers per question is now [officially](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/255554) not a criterion for graduation anymore and it never really was. Actually, TeX had 2.4 answers per question [when it graduated](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2148/tex-latex-and-friends) and [other](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12612/skeptics) [sites](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4964/chemistry) had far less. The almost only criterion for graduation now is [having 10 questions per day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/255554).

The numbers on Area 51 are only rough indicators of site health and the listed criteria cannot be generalised over site topics. Having only one answer per question (on average) would indeed be worrisome (at least given a 100 % answered ratio), as it means that we are not proposing alternative solutions at all. We are having much more than this and as long as we do, there is nothing to worry, in particular as such an answer ratio is the norm amongst language sites.

As far as I can see, there is no indication that our site is unhealthy or that anybody regards it such. What we need for graduation is more questions, but there are also many sites with far fewer questions per day (see [this overview](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday)).